# how to dynamically change the list items on searching through AutoCompleteTextView ?

Tags: android

can anyone please suggest me how can I Change items of custom list whenever any text is entered in auto complete text view for searching words from that custom list. I know, how to implement auto complete text view and setting its threshold, but I want to manipulate custom list's item through auto complete text view without generating its own list of words. I think I am clear.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: please have a look on given answer :) hope will help you

Comment: To get good answers on StackOverflow you should show some effort to solve the problem by yourself and show what you have achieved by adding your code to the question and describe what doesn't work as expected or what error you get. StackOverflow is not a site to ask for code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a TextWatcher to your edittext or autocomplete text

Answer (score 0):

you can implement textWatcher and then use this code.

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    ArrayList<CommonListviewBean> list = new ArrayList<CommonListviewBean>();//here bean is use for initialization
    for(int i=0;i<_itemArrayList.size();i++){
        CommonListviewBean bean = (CommonListviewBean)_itemArrayList.get(i);
        if(bean.get_text().contains(s)){
            list.add(bean);
        }

    }
    _adapater = new ListViewAdapater(activityname.this, list);
    _adapater.notifyDataSetChanged();=
    _listview.setAdapter(_adapater);
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
}
```